# Est-ce que le verbe "quitter" peut signifier "mourir"?

Tags: sens, expressions

J'étais en train de lire du passage sur la vie d'un homme qui s'est éteint à 88 ans, sur lequel j'ai tombé par hasard l'usage du verbe "quitter" pour signifier qu'il est mort.

L'usage:

> Bien qu'il nous ait quitté à 88 ans, …

Souvent en anglais, on peut utiliser le mot "die" (mourir) pour remplacer par "leave" (quitter). Est-ce qu'on peut le faire en français également?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Il nous a quitté à 88 ans.
>
> Elle nous a quitté le jour de la fête de la musique.

Dans un discours ou une conversation durant un deuil, pour les proches et ceux qui ont connu la personne qui est 'partie' : on ne prononce pas le mot *mort*.

> Il est mort (ou décédé) le ../../.. (ou à 88 ans).

Dans un rapport administratif ou pour parler d'un disparu pour lequel nous n'avons pas d'attache particulière, pour signaler qu'on est au courant d'un décès.

Comment: Pourquoi y a-t-il un deuxième "e" à la fin de décidé(e) ? Elle est le sujet, donc le participe passé ne fait pas l'accord avec elle . Ou est-ce que j'ai tort ?

Comment: @BenKnoble -- Exact, mais c'était pour *quitté* :)

Comment: Quel dommage -- j'ai perdu la tête, hein?

Comment: "Elle nous a quittés" - avec un "s", non?

Comment: @Vérace -- "Elle a quitté nous", c'est cette singulière personne qui est partie, ce n'est pas *nous* qui avons fait l'action ; en revanches "nous sommes quittés par elle" (ce n'est pas du bon français, il vaudrait mieux  "nous nous sommes quittés", et on passe alors du verbe *avoir* au verbe *être*) pourrait aller, mais "Nous l'avons quitté" est tout à fait correct, selon mon correcteur orthographique et mes souvenirs anciens des problèmes d'accord et de participe passé avec le verbe avoir.

Comment: Tu veux parier? "Elle nous a quittés" est la forme correcte de la phrase. Elle a quitté quoi? Nous! "Nous" c'est un pluriel, forcément. Avec accord, ceci implique  "quittés" (ou "quittées" si "nous" sommes des femmes).

Comment: @Vérace -- N'étant pas grammairien pour un sou, je ne parierai même pas une lire italienne du siècle dernier :). En principe *on ne quitte pas **quoi**, on quitte **qui*** quant il s'agit de *nous*. "Elle a quitté ses appartements", "Elle s'est barrée de ses appartements" (avec le verbe *être* l'accord est nécessaire), c'est elle qui réalise l'action et qui donne l'accord du verbe. Parier pour "Elle a fuites ses sœurs", même si j'ai une petite idée du résultat... En revanche ouvrez une question, il y a peut-être des cas de figure possibles : mon correcteur d'orthographe accepte les deux cas !

Comment: Merci de ta réponse.  Je vais ouvrir une question. "Elle a fuites ses soeurs" est ridicule. "Elle les a fuites" ne l'est pas. À la prochaine.

Answer (score 6):

Oui, mais principalement sous la forme « il *nous* a quitté » tandis que « il a quitté [quelqu'un] » signifie tout à fait autre chose.

En revanche, on entend parfois « il est parti » ou « il s'est en allé » (de façon plus formelle : « il s'en est allé ») car les verbes partir ou s'en aller n'ont pas besoin de complément.

Comment: +1 - "Il est parti" peut aussi signifier "son esprit est parti".

Answer (score 3):

Oui c'est comme en anglais, le verbe quitter peut signifier mourir. Dans l'exemple : "Il nous a quitté à 88 ans" signifie "Il est mort à 88 ans". Ou je suis tombée par hasard sur cet exemple : Il va nous quitter" (ou encore "il va partir"), signifie qu'il va mourir.

Answer (score 1):

Effectivement, ''Quitter'' peut très bien signifier mourir puisque la notion de ''Quitter'' entraîne une notion de ''partir'' provisoirement ou définitivement.

Answer (score -1):

Bien sur que nous pouvons traduire mort pas quitté,c'est une façon moins brutal de dire que l'homme n'est plus en vie

Comment: Mort (nom ou adjectif ?) ne veut absolument pas dire quitté (participe passé). Il est inutile de donner des réponse - de surcroît fausse - quand une réponse correcte a déjà été donnée.